# Multiple Android apps depending on the same fragment from a module with different layout files

Tags: android, module

My company is making a 'clone' of its current app, which will mostly have the same functionality, but the UI will be quite different. Some screens only have different colors, while others require different layouts completely.

The app is currently split into multiple modules that can be used in both apps, making future maintenance easier. However, I'm struggling to find a good way of using different layouts for each app in fragments.

Ex: Fragment A has layout X in the first app. Fragment A needs layout Y in the second app, which will be somewhat different but will contain the same views with the same ids.

My current idea: create modules that only contain layout files. Add the modules as an app-level dependency and inject them into each fragment using dagger. This feels like a lot of work and also means that the modules containing the fragments have no reference to the ids in the layouts, making databinding and even findViewById() impossible, unless I also inject the ids. You can see how this becomes a huge problem very quickly.

Another idea: use different flavors in each module for colors and layouts. But this will make building the project quite complicated and it means that the 2 different apps will have to reference different flavors of each module's artifact.

Anyone out there with better ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use Flavours (a.k.a. "Build Variants") and create different Layout/Java folders.

- /src

  - /main

    - /java

      - /..../ExampleClass.java (don't instantiate/use this Class directly but use Flavour's Extended versions)
    - /res

      - /layout/example.xml
  - /Flavour1 (used by both Debug and Release)
  - /Flavour1Debug

    - /java/.../ExtendedExampleClass.java
  - /Flavour1Release

    - /java/.../ExtendedExampleClass.java
    - /res/layout/example_modified1.xml
  - /Flavour2 (used by both Debug and Release)
  - /Flavour2Debug

    - /java/.../ExtendedExampleClass.java
  - /Flavour2Release

    - /java/.../ExtendedExampleClass.java
    - /res/layout/example_modified2.xml

In this way you can use same Class's (the "*ExtendedExampleClass*") Methods/Fields in all Flavours even if Layout/Resources are different.
Obliviously all Extended Class should expose same Method/Fields or in each Flavours you should create other Classes extensions that use dedicated Methods/Fields.

Comment: This could work nicely for an app that is not made up of different modules. But since a lot of these classes will be in different modules, it would mean creating and uploading different flavors to a maven repository for each individual module, then using only the flavored artifact in each app. This feels like it would be harder to maintain in the future compared to just injecting the layout id in each fragment

Comment: App Project should be the only Flavored, the other Module's Classes needs to be Extended in the App Project (different package names are allowed inside it) and only those extended classes should be used in a way similarly to what I shown you. There isn't any other way.